# Paper of Boutot-Carayol in `Courbes modulaires et courbes de Shimura'

Tags: reference-request, shimura-varieties, rigid-analytic-geometry

I am trying to obtain a copy of the following

> J.-F. Boutot and H. Carayol, Uniformisation p-adique des courbes de Shimura: les
>   théorèmes de Čerednik et de Drinfel'd , Astérisque No. 196-197 (1991), 7, 45–158 (1992)

According to the SMF website, this is contained in (editor listed as Guy Henniart)

> Courbes modulaires et courbes de Shimura (Orsay, 1987/1988). Astérisque No. 196-197 (1991), 7, 45--158 (1992). MR1141456 (93c:11041)

Unfortunately the SMF website says that this is out of print, and I cannot find a copy anywhere. I would appreciate if anyone could tell me how/where to obtain a copy (preferably in electronic form).

Comment: I was surprised to see that Asterisque is not in Numdam. Can somebody in the know explain why?

Comment: Most Asterisque volumes are not, in my experience.

Comment: Do you have a copy now or not ? I can send you an original copy in French !

Comment: http://www.numdam.org/issues/AST_1991__196-197__1_0/ This should work for the Asterisque paper

Answer (score 2):

See this question. [Drinfeld's "Coverings of p-adic symmetric domains" translated?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/77829/drinfelds-coverings-of-p-adic-symmetric-domains-translated)

Somewhat coincidentally, in a comment regarding the paper of your interest (Boutot and Carayol), Thomas Riepe (Oct 12 '11 at 5:19) writes: "Cameron Franc has translated it into english:"

However, I am unable to get the given link to work, or this one either: http://lordnoron.com/cam/documents/bctranslation.pdf

See also the acceptied answer to this question ["Bad" reduction of Shimura curves via dual graphs](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/51935/bad-reduction-of-shimura-curves-via-dual-graphs) which has yet another dead link.

The translation itself was announced on his blog: https://cfranc.wordpress.com/2010/01/18/boutot-carayol-translation and at least at that point he had only translated Chapter 2.

Comment: I contacted Cameron Franc and he informed me that he completed the translation, and he supplied me with a copy. He mentioned that he will make it available on his website when he has time, with the caveat that it has not been proofread.

Comment: Just wanted to post that the translation by Franc is now up here: http://www-personal.umich.edu/~francc/files/bctranslation.pdf